# Difference between である and だ in the written form

Tags: grammar, copula

My grammar book states that である is used as copula in the written form to express ideas in a neutral fashion and that だ is also used in the written form to, quote, "sound more objective".
But doesn't "sound more objective" = neutral point of view?

So, what are the different usages of である and だ in the written form?

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/18692/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/12374/9831

Comment: Ty! I saw the posts you mentioned but I thought for some reason they were referring to the usage of だ in the spoken language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to ["A Dictionary of Intermediate Japanese Grammar", page 32](https://japbase.neocities.org/intermediate/Intermediate%E3%81%A7%E3%81%82%E3%82%8B.png):

> The plain forms are used in formal writing, for example, in professional articles and editorials.  Although である style is more formal than だ style, the two styles are ofter used together.

So, である is more formal than だ.

Comment: Ty! So, as pointed out by Chocolate, is safe to say that, apart from being more formal, だ more subjective than である?